# Set ContentPresenter ContentTemplate on value change in generated field

Tags: wpf

I have am attempting to build a tree view where:
1. The TreeViewItems are generated by a list in my model.
2. Each TreeViewItem contains a ComboBox, and a dynamic element whose template I want to change based on the value selected in the ComboBox.

Here is my current `xaml` code.

```
<Window x:Class="MyTestWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyTestWPF"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:NodeTypeToTemplateConverter x:Key="NodeTypeToTemplateConverter"/>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Template1">
            <TextBlock Text="Template 1" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Template2">
            <TextBlock Text="Template 2" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <Style x:Key="MyNodeTemplate" TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource Template1}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=NodeType}">
                    <DataTrigger.Value>
                        <local:NodeTypesEnum>Type1</local:NodeTypesEnum>
                    </DataTrigger.Value>
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource NodeTypeToTemplateConverter}}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyTreeNode}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GetAvailableNodeType}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=NodeType}" />
                <ContentPresenter Style="{StaticResource MyNodeTemplate}" Content="{Binding}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <TreeView x:Name="MyTree" ItemsSource="{Binding MyTreeModel}" />
</Window>
```

And its code-behind:

```
using System.Windows;
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new
        {
            MyTreeModel = new MyTreeNode[] {
                new MyTreeNode() { Name = "1", Nodes = new MyTreeNode[] { new MyTreeNode() { Name= "2" } } }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The tree node type:

```
namespace MyTestWPF
{
    public class MyTreeNode
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public NodeTypesEnum NodeType { get; set; }
        public MyTreeNode[] Nodes { get; set; }
        public NodeTypesEnum[] GetAvailableNodeType()
        {
            return new NodeTypesEnum[] { NodeTypesEnum.Type1, NodeTypesEnum.Type2 };
        }
    }

    public enum NodeTypesEnum
    {
        Type1 = 0,
        Type2 = 1
    }
}
```

The Converter (`NodeTypeToTemplateConverter`) receives the whole ViewModel, and returns the name of the relevant template based on values in the model.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace MyTestWPF
{
    public class NodeTypeToTemplateConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if((value as MyTreeNode).NodeType == NodeTypesEnum.Type1)
            {
                return "Template1";
            } else
            {
                return "Template2";
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the above code causes a stack overflow exception. The first item in the TreeView endlessly calls `NodeTypeToTemplateConverter`'s Convert method.

I figured it had to do with the `DataTrigger.Value`. Setting that to a value different from the default `NodeType` allows the page to load without overflow, but the moment any `ComboBox` is set to `NodeType1`, **stack overflow**.

I attempted to simply remove the `DataTrigger.Value` element, but that causes the Converter to never be called at all...

How can I dynamically build the template name based on the value selected by its neighboring ComboBox?

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when asking a question on SO to get better help.

Comment: @mm8 Sorry. I've added the rest of the code in full where the problem is reproduced. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use a DataTemplateSelector rather than a converter.

```
public class ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate Template1 { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate Template2 { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        //Logic to select template based on 'item' value.
        if (item == <template1Value>) return Template1;  //TODO: replace <template1Value>
        else if (item == <template2Value>) return Template2;  //TODO: replace <template2Value>
        else return new DataTemplate();
    }
}

<local:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector x:Key="ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector">
    <local:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector.Template1>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </local:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector.Template1>
    <local:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector.Template2>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </local:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector.Template2>
</local:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector>

<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding NodeType}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector}"/>
```

I have not fully tested this code, so let me know if you have any issues.

**EDIT:**

The template selector is only executed when the content changes so this won't work if you use {Binding}. A workaround for this would be to have the DataTemplate content bind to the parent's DataContext.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="" DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentPresenter}}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

If this workaround is not acceptable, there are other ways to do this as well.

Comment: So, this works and reacts to change in the selected ComboBox item, if I set the `Content="{Binding NodeType}"` but leaves me with another problem. In my example, I set `Content="{Binding}"` because the template being loaded needs the full MyTreeNode DataContext object. Following your example, only the NodeType property gets passed.

Comment: I guess I should have asked before editing the answer, do you need the whole object in the template selector, or in the DataTemplate?

Comment: In the data template